# React Query error when making axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, tanstackreact-query

I am having trouble with this error message every time I try to send an axios request to fetch data.
'**Starting with v5, only the "Object" form is allowed when calling query related functions. Please use the error stack to find the culprit call.**'

I am still learning react so I'm currently unable to find the culprit through the dev tools.

This is the topmost component where I called the react query provider

App.js

```
import {QueryClient, QueryClientProvider} from '@tanstack/react-query';

function App() {
const client = new QueryClient();

return(
<div>
<QueryClientProvider client={client}>
    <ReactQuery/>
</QueryClientProvider>
</div>
);
};
```

This is the component - React Query

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar4 from './Navbar4';
import ReactHome from './pages/ReactHome';
import ReactProfile from './pages/ReactProfile';
import About from './pages/About';

const ReactQuery = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <h4>React Query</h4>
        <Router>
        <Navbar4/>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<ReactHome/>}/>
                <Route path='/reactProfile' element={<ReactProfile/>}/>
                <Route path='about' element={<About/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ReactQuery;
```

And this is the "ReactHome" component, where I submit the request.

ReactHome.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {useQuery} from '@tanstack/react-query';
import Axios from 'axios';

const ReactHome = () => {
    const {data} = useQuery(['cat'], () => {
        return Axios.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact").then((res) => res.data);
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <p>React Home - {data.fact}</p>

        </div>
    )
}

export default ReactHome;
```

I am trying to use react query to make an axios request to an API. I keep getting errors whenever I do so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [API reference for `useQuery()`](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/reference/useQuery) in @tanstack/react-query v5+.

The hook accepts an object with options as opposed to separate parameters.

```js
const { data } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ["cat"],
  queryFn: async () => (await Axios.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact")).data,
});
```

See also [Migrating to TanStack Query v5](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/migrating-to-v5#supports-a-single-signature-one-object)

> useQuery and friends used to have many overloads in TypeScript - different ways how the function can be invoked. Not only this was tough to maintain, type wise, it also required a runtime check to see which type the first and the second parameter, to correctly create options.
>
> now we only support the object format.

Comment: Alright. let me try this

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: I see how you included the async function to avoid the break situation where the variablie is still null. 
I reconfigured it back to the way i wanted as wanted to learn some other aspects as well and used this to compensate-

 `<p>{data?.fact}</p>`

Anyway, I just wanted to appreciate the detailed answer once again. Gracias.

Comment: @Being47 I just try to avoid `.then()` when `async` / `await` is an option. You don't have to though

Comment: Thanks. I'd take that into consideration